# chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener not always receiving a message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to send a node id from a script running from a popup page to a script running from a tab page. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't; I haven't found any rhyme or reason to explain why it does or doesn't.

Here's my popup code that sends the message:

```
$(".node-list-item").click( function()
        {
            nodeid = $(this).attr("nid");
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: "tab.html"}, function(tab)
            {
                console.log("Sending nid: " + nodeid);
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { nid: nodeid});
            });
        });
```

Here's the code that receives it:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, response)
        {
            console.log(message);
            add_notice("Received node: " + message.nid);
            show_node(message.nid);
        });
```

Why would this work sometimes but not all the time? I do know that the sending function always sends a value, or at least the console.log function is running.

Comment: I am having this same issue and am unable to accurately debug why it only works 20% of the time.